# keyboard shortcuts doesn't work in applications after changing layout

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use some shortcuts in applications like ( phpstrom, sublimeText, ... ), but when I change keyboard layout these shortcuts doesn't works.
For example I use ctrl+z for Redo, but when I change keyboard layout to Persian these shortcuts doesn't works!.
I checked some applications but I have this issue exists in all of them so I think it is related to Ubuntu.
My Ubuntu version is 14.4
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the way keys are mapped for the Persian layout. For example, the letter Z might not be mapped to the exact key (the one with the Z written on it). I don't know how the Persian layout is, but perhaps you could try finding which key corresponds to Z (if it's not the Z key) and try Ctrl+that key to see if it works as Redo. Then you'll have to check this for each shortcut you use.  I repeat, it's some sort of educated guess from me...

Comment: I checked your solution but didn't worked.